# Mongoose some field are not inserted

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema, nosql

im trying to insert a document in mongodb, 
my code is:

```
// Creating Schema
var ReportSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
host: String,
port: Number
},
{strict: false});
// declaring a Model
var testModel = {
        host: "localhost",
        port: 4444
        }

// Schema needed
var TestReports = mongoose.model('TestReports',ReportSchema);
var reportModel = new TestReports(testModel);
reportModel.save(function(err){
        if(err){
            throw err;
            } else{
                console.log("inserted :)");

                }           
        });
mongoose.disconnect();

});
```

the code is working properly but sometimes the json i recieved contains additional fields is there's any way to allow those field to be inserted without adding them to the schema? any help would be appreciated

Thank you.

Comment: Then add them to the Schema... the very usage of a Schema is to provide a blueprint to encompass all the data...

Comment: So, theres no way around that?

Comment: Of course not. Just mark those fields as optional.

Comment: `strict: false` should be doing what you're looking for (http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict) - since you've already specified that, I'm not sure why it's not working?

Comment: Okay, Thank you @AndrewLi,

Comment: @Alex , yes i did some search and i found that solution but when inserting data it only insert the data figuring in the schema and ignore the rest.